# Putting a matrix inside of caption gives \caption has an extra }

Tags: graphics, errors, captions

I am trying to insert a matrix inside of the caption of an image.

[image]

The compiled pdf displays the picture, but gives an error that says:

> \caption@{indecipherable} has an extra }

[image]

**Can someone please point to me where I might have inserted an extra `}`? Because I don't see it anywhere!**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics{jpg-to-pdf.pdf}
    \end{center}
    \caption{$x^\star =\begin{bmatrix} \alpha, \beta, \gamma \end{bmatrix}$}
    \label{fig:just_picture_of_cute_cat}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone also know what *ydblarg* is?

Comment: Oh my a cute cat ;-) .. But try `\protect\begin{bmatrix}....\protect\end{bmatrix}`, and remove the `\begin{center}...\end{center}` there, it does nothing good there

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, is there like a one-line self-explanatory answer as to why \protect is necessary?

Comment: `\begin{matrix}` is a fragile command, i.e. it breaks during the write process to the `.aux`/`.lof`, so this breaking is prevented with `\protect`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Never heard of such thing as a fragile command, but this is good enough for me!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I'm surprised! Why is `\matrix` a fragile command? I thought that fragile commands were usually commands like `\footnote` or `\figure`, where the arguments might need to be saved and typeset later or in a different place. Though…now that I think about it, `\lstinline` is fragile and doesn't fit this pattern, either; extra kudos if you know that one, too. :-)

Comment: @wchargin: `matrix` is an environment that uses `\matrix@check\matrix\env@matrix`, i.e. commands defined with `amsmath` or latex.ltx itself, this is not robust.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\begin{matrix}` and `\end{matrix}` are fragile commands that do not survive the writing process being connected to `\caption` -- the content is written to the `.aux` file and to the `.lof` file later on with `\@writefile`.

In order to prevent the fragility there, the commands `\begin{matrix}` and `\end{matrix}` have to be protected with `\protect`, i.e. `\protect\begin{matrix}` and `\protect\end{matrix}`.

If the protection is not activated, `\caption` prematurely encounters a `}` which is not the ending bracket of its mandatory argument.

A better way is to apply the optional argument of `\caption` and prevent the writing of math content to the `.aux` and `.lof` file, i.e. use the `short` and the `long caption` style.

However, if fragile content should be written in the `short` caption argument, the protection must be enabled again.

Alternatively use robust commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering

  \includegraphics{ente}
  \caption{$x^\star =\protect\begin{bmatrix} \alpha, \beta, \gamma \protect\end{bmatrix}$}
  \caption[Foo content]{$x^\star =\begin{bmatrix} \alpha, \beta, \gamma \end{bmatrix}$}
  \label{fig:just_picture_of_cute_cat}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a cat :-P

[image]

Comment: Wow, magic! A cat turned into a duck!

Comment: @samcarter: A Harry-Potter cat ;-)

Comment: But you see, I want my picture to remain a cat in a pair of trousers, if \protect necessarily converts the image to a duck, then it is better to look for some workaround instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sheppy: ;-) Provide the image file and we're talking

Comment: You have a typo in your answer: `\protect\end{protect}` should be `\protect\end{matrix}` :)

Comment: @hooy: Yes, thanks. I've corrected it. It was correct in the code, however.

Answer (score 5):

Add `\protect` on entering and leaving the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{vent_cat}
    \caption{$x^\star =\protect\begin{bmatrix} \alpha, \beta, \gamma \protect\end{bmatrix}$}
    \label{fig:just_picture_of_cute_cat}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Yours is quite comprehensive. I guess that  while you were writing details, I was looking for a relevant ‘cute cat’ from TeX Avery's gallery. I can withdraw my answer since it doesn't  add whatever to yours, technically speaking.

Comment: No, keep it please, I just wanted to know whether I was missing something.