# LaTeX giving me error for picture caption but output looks right

Tags: floats, captions, matrices

I entered the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\DeclareUSUnit\mile{mi}

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[H]
       \centering{\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{MECH335MidtermPlot1.png}}
       \caption{Linearized phase plot about the equilibrium $\mathbf{x}^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$.}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Argument of \@tempf has an extra }. ...= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$.}
Paragraph ended before \@tempf was complete. ...= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$.}
```

However, the output looks fine as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it so that the error doesn't appear?

Comment: The following gives no error for me: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
   \includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{example-image-a}
       \caption{Linearized phase plot about the equilibrium $\mathbf{x}^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$.}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: Adding the `[demo]` flag didn't work for me. I still get that error.

Comment: The demo flag was just because I don't have access to your image.  That exact code above gives you an error?  Please post a complete but minimal document that produces the error on your machine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what machine/software did you use? I use TeXStudio

Comment: I use `miktex` and `texniccenter` (the latter mostly out of momentum).

Comment: I looked more into the error, it's just that when I put the `bmatrix` command, the error appears.

Comment: Hey @Scott H., I managed to find my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364994/putting-a-matrix-inside-of-caption-gives-caption-has-an-extra?rq=1

Thank you for helping out!

Comment: I've just voted to close as a duplicate, since the OP found the answer in another question.